# Indian recruiters trying to recruit for tech position

Tags: recruitment

So, this is just a weird question, but I'm wondering how it has worked with others. It's the new years and I've been getting a lot of contacts from recruiters, directly from companies and recruiting agencies. A few of the recruiters I've gotten contacted by have been great leads, in fact one of them is a near guaranteed job in about a month, but not quitting until I have an offer.

Since the new year, I've been contacted by A LOT of Indian recruiters recently. Never had luck with a single one. One case was an Indian recruiter for a company and she seemed nice, but she never let me or the recruiting agency that I was going through know that they decided to move on from the job opportunity. They ghosted both me and the recruiting agency.

A lot of the other recruiters are asking for jobs that have nothing to do with my background, are what I would call very low-ball places that pay sub-standard, or are sketchy as hell emails with misspelled company names on the email.

My question is if I'm better off ignoring most of these or have some people had some much better experiences than I have? This question mostly applies to the ones with really thick accents and some poor english, but in general, all the ones I've talked to have been bad experience for me.

Edit: My main goal is to understand other's experience here. Maybe there is a different common denominator among all of this that will help me make a better decision on it. There's a lot of weird things here and someone might be able to give me a better idea on what's going on there.

Comment: I am voting to close as there is no goal we can address. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Flagging to close because this is soliciting discussion, polling, and anecdotes, not answers.

Answer (score 5):

You have to research the company.

There are lots of recruiters with Indian names.

Indian consulting companies in the USA have a terrible reputation and they have earned every bit of it.

Generally speaking, these firms will never hire you - they are required by law to look for an American before they bring in their h1B, so they send out some emails to people they know won't take the job and say that they have looked.

You also have to worry about them taking your resume, putting someone else's name on it, then submitting it to an employer.

If you get a bad feeling about a recruiter - imagine what employers feel. The labor market is the strongest it has been in living memory, you don't have to waste your time with their rubbish.

Comment: "The labor market is the strongest it has been in living memory" - ah, I remember those days. Good times.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is if I'm better off ignoring most of these or have some people had some much better experiences than I have?

I wouldn't generalize and give each recruiter a chance, and judge them on a case-by-case basis.

Perhaps you are seeing a trend here, but that doesn't mean that all of those recruiters will be a bad experience (job-hunting takes time, rarely one finds a job on the first try).

So, try giving recruiters a chance, and use your judgment to discern if the position is convenient for you or not, so you can proceed or stop the process, so no one wastes their valuable time here.

Answer (score 2):

The barrier to entry to become a recruiter is very low. You just need a computer and an internet connection. And for a phone, you just need VOIP. That basically means anyone can be a recruiter, just like anyone can become a spammer.

So you're basically asking us if we discriminate against someone based on their national origin or their accent. Do you realize what you're asking us?

And to that question, I say "No, I do not discriminate." Myself, I am foreign-born and I have a heavy accent. And I can tell you I hang up the phone on any recruiter and all recruiters. It doesn't matter who they are. Where they're from. "accent or no accent". I hang up the phone on all of them.

Now if someone you trust strongly recommends a recruiter to you, by all means, talk to that recruiter and talk to that recruiter whether he has an accent or not. But that's the only exception in my book.

In my opinion, you'll have far more success if you contact an employer directly since your resume won't come with the added 40% premium that an employer will have to pay in addition to your salary.

Also note, that some 3rd party recruiters are ok if they have an email address sporting the domain name of the employer they're working for. That usually means those recruiters already have an arrangement with that employer. You definitely shouldn't ignore those.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of employers: bad, medium, and great ones. For simplicity, we say it's 20% / 60 % / 20%

Imagine each of those companies wants to fill 10 positions. The great company likely doesnt need to that much to generate interest, and so with relatively little effort, they can fill their positions.

The medium ones fill their positions with a medium effort. So the positions stay open longer.

The bad companies: A lot of people reject that company at some point in the interview process. So after some time, what should be like 15% bad offers initialy, can approach 50%!

If you factor in that bad employees likely have less qualms about contacting people that are just vaguely a fit, and also their turn over is likely higher, It can be even more.

So, to get less exposure to bad ones: polish your profile, so that more god recruiters start contacting you. Prepare a canned written reponse about your minimum requirement. Stop pointless calls the 2nd you realise the pointlessness!
Don't even answer to recruiters you aren't interested in.

Answer (score 1):

It's a sad fact that hiring companies often "ghost" candidates for jobs.  Don't let it bother you too much.  (When you are a hiring manager, you can do things better than that.)

Your time is valuable. You only have enough to spend with a few recruiters. If you have one or two you like, work with them.

The good recruiters make it their mission to match you to a good job for you. How can you tell they're any good?  Ask them to describe the interviewing and hiring process for the jobs they send you to. If they're good, you will get a helpful conversation from that kind of question.

And, if you get misspelled rubbish emails, you can guess that they also send misspelled rubbish to hiring managers. You don't want that kind of representation. So ignore them.